# Coding a convex problem in CVX

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, cvx

I am new to CVX and am trying to simulate this convex problem I found in a paper.

$$\min_{\gamma,\mathbf{mu},\mathbf{G},\mathbf{\Omega},t} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{G}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{G}^H)+t \\ s.t. -t-\frac{\gamma}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\log(1-\frac{2\mu_i}{\gamma})-\gamma \log(\delta)\leq0\\\mu_1\geq\mu_2\geq\ldots\geq\mu_n\geq0\\2\mu_1<\gamma\\ \text{S}_k(C^{1/2} \Lambda C^{1/2})\leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \mu_i \quad \forall k = 0,1,\dots,n-1\\
\text{Tr}(\Omega C)\leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\mu_i\\\Omega\geq \Lambda$$

where $$\Lambda = (\mathbf{G}\mathbf{H}-\mathbf{I})^H(\mathbf{G}\mathbf{H}-\mathbf{I})$$ and $S_k(\mathbf{A})$ is the sum of the largest $k$ eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$. In the problem, the scalar $\delta$, matrices $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are assumed known. $\mathbf{C}$ is symmetric positive definite. I am finding it difficult to reformulate the first constraint with the log summation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a nonconvex problem so you will never be able to implement this using CVX (the name CVX tells you why). I suspect you've flipped a bunch of signs.

Comment: Are you sure? The paper I am reading clearly says that it is convex. The paper can be found at http://bit.ly/1ycHCVa

Comment: As I said, you must have written down the wrong model. $t=-\infty$ is optimal, and $\Sigma =0$ is trivially feasible and there is no reason to pick any other choice, making the two last constraints redundant.

Comment: I meant $\Omega=0$

Comment: You are write. I had made a mistake. The direction of the inequality in the first correction was wrong.Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: Still non-convex in the last inequality (making $\Omega=0$ feasible thus making the last two constraints redundant)

Comment: I had omitted a constraint, thinking it would not be relevant to the convexity and since I could easily implement the constraint in CVX. I frankly, don't see how it could alter the convexity. Do you still think it is non-convex? Thank you.

Comment: There's really no way CVX will solve this. The objective function is basically `sum_square_abs(vec(G*sqrtm(C)))+t`, so that's not a problem. I suspect that the final quadratic form can be expressed as an LMI using a Schur complement (assuming that is intended as a semidefinite inequality; if it's elementwise, it is not convex). But the constraints with the logarithms are the issue, and there's way around it. Even if it is convex (and I am by no means certain) it is beyond the scope of the solvers CVX uses.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks a lot.I know that this was solved using SeDuMi. I ll take it up with the author of the paper. Thanks once again.

Comment: Once again, the constraints only make sense if you have introduced $\Omega$ as an *upper* bound of the quadratic form, i.e., $\Omega \succeq \Lambda$, which is convex after a Schur complement. Also note that you should use that upper bound in the $S_k$ operator, to get a simple SDP-representable function (and with first $k$ eigenvalues, I assume you mean $k$ largest)

Comment: BTW, the sum-k eigenvalues is not convex either, as you have an unsymmetric matrix in there. Perhaps you mean $S_k((GH-I)C(GH-I)^H)$, which is convex and SDP representable by introducing yet another matrix and applying a Schur complement

Comment: Good catch. Anyway, what is clear is that this was not solved as written.

Comment: The log stuff is convex, as it is a negated perspective of a logarithm, alternatively it is a difference of a kullback-leibler term and an entropy. If you wish, you can open a thread on the YALMIP google groups forum and I will show you an implementation using YALMIP + the solver scs which solves the problem exactly using semidefinite+exponential cones.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I am trying to re-derive the problem on my own. I will get in touch if I get stuck again. Thank you once again :)

Comment: Ah, I am glad you managed to figure out the logarithm term, Johan. One can indeed express that in YALMIP as well as CVX. And 3.0 supports the exponential cones natively. But it is clear there is a fair bit of rewriting to do first. There is still no way this was solved using SeDuMi, *unless* they used CVX's successive approximation method.

Comment: I got the correct equations and made the edit. @JohanLöfberg was right. The inequality direction needed to be changed and the expression for the sum of k largest eigenvalues was also wrong. I have made the corrections in the question.

Comment: The problem is convex now. I was able to implement the constraints involving $\Lambda$ as an LMI using the Schur complement approach. But am still stuck with the $\log$ function in the second constraint. Right now, I am solving the problem for a particular $\gamma$ using CVX and using `fmincon` as a wrapper to minimize over $\gamma$. The resulting simulation is painfully slow. @MichaelGrant Can you please suggest a more elegant approach?

Comment: As I said above, the problem is convex as you can write $\gamma \log(1-2\mu/\gamma)$ as a negated Kullback-Leibler Available in both YALMIP and CVX and leads to problems with a mixed sdp-exponential cone, which can be solved using the solver scs.